# eventRender in Fullcalendar calendar disappears

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a problem with the function eventRender after adding the eventRender line: function (event, element), the calendar stops displaying. I have added (probably good?) Libraries. Fullcelendar version 3.4.0.

I use eventRender twice. Once to display the description in the event bar and once to display the pop-up label.

```js
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.css">

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable:false,
    locale: 'pl',
    header:{
     left:'prev,next ',
     center:'title',
     right:'today'
    },
    events: 'load.php',
    selectable:true,
    selectHelper:true,
    rendering: 'background',



eventRender: function(event, element, view, info)
    {
      element.find(".fc-title").html("ID: " + event.id + " - " + event.title);
       if(event.approved == "1") {
      element.css('background-color', '#f26e1e');
    }else { 
element.find(".fc-title").html("DO AKCEPTACJI " + "ID: " + event.id + " - " + event.title);
}
    }

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({ /* qtip is not included with fullcalendar */
            content: event.description
        });
    }
    
   });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors in your browser's Console when this happens? That sounds like the most likely reason for the problem described. If you have an issue with JavaScript code not running then checking the Console should be the first thing you do

Comment: P.s. I would point out that you have defined eventRender twice here. That makes no sense. You can't define the same option twice.... the later one will just override the earlier one. If you want more code to run during the eventRender callback then just add that to your original function

Comment: `eventRender: function(event, element, view, info)
    {
     element.qtip({ /* qtip is not included with fullcalendar */
            content: ("Szczegóły: " + event.description + ", Gości: " + event.guest)
        });
      element.find(".fc-title").html("ID: " + event.id + " - " + event.title);
       if(event.approved == "1") {
      element.css('background-color', '#f26e1e');
    }else { 
element.find(".fc-title").html("DO AKCEPTACJI " + "ID: " + event.id + " - " + event.title);
}
    }`

Comment: It was a solution! A double call caused it not to work. Combined functions work well. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you fixed it. But you should add your solution as an Answer below, then people can vote on it. Code and solutions don't belong in the comments :-)